# DirectoryChooser doesnt detect Unicode Characters - Possible Bug

Tags: java, javafx-2

`DirectoryChooser` of JavaFX doesn't accept files with say foreign language characters (non-ascii).

```
DirectoryChooser dc = dcb.title("Place Renamed Pictures In").build();
    if(op!=null){
        File file = new File("/users/some/default/path");
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            dc.setInitialDirectory(file);
        }
    }
    File selected = dc.showDialog(stage);
    System.out.println(selected+" "+selected.isDirectory()+" "+selected.exists());
```

While choosing the directory in the dialog. It does show all files. But when you accept and choose some non-ascii one, the above prints `/Users/a/prøveråfå false false` which is vague.

This behavior is on Mac. It was a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7193966) before (Before it did not even list non-ascii files, now it does), but weird behavior with DialogChooser

My Config: Java 1.7._10. Mac OS X 10.7.5

EDIT:
Doing

```
File f = new File("Users/a/prøveråfå");
f.exists();
f.isDirectory();
```

returns true in both cases

Comment: file a bug report at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/

Comment: Also try a recent [Java 8 build](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and see if the bug has already been fixed.

Comment: Tried it. Infact my default is Java 8, later downloaded other versions and tried. All report it

Comment: Seems like it is a bug with Java FX